# Calculate the distance between 2 point using openlayers

Tags: coordinates, openlayers, distance, between

I've been trying to implement this using a previously suggested solution

```
var Geographic  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
var Mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");


function distanceBetweenPoints(latlng1, latlng2){
        var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlng1.lon, latlng1.lat).transform(Geographic, Mercator);
        var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlng2.lon, latlng2.lat).transform(Geographic, Mercator);       
        return point1.distanceTo(point2);
    }
```

However I get "point1.distanceTo is not a function". I can't find the function in current documentation, so I guess it has been withdrawn.

Is there an alternative approach? I've found several article but they give solutions using distanceTo.

Comment: I suggest using the getLength() function provided by OL on LineString Geometry. Take a look at this example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

Create a linestring first using the two points you have.

As far as i see distanceTo() is no longer a function in OL 6, but i don't know what versions you're using.

Comment: You could use the `OpenLayers.Util.distVincenty` method  http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Util-js.html

Comment: I'm using OL v 6.3.1. distVincenty sounds great but docs link is for OL v 2. 6.3.1 hasn't got this function. Am I misunderstanding the versioning here is v2 really new or really old.

Comment: I gave an OL2 link because all your code above is version 2 and I would not expect it get beyond the first line if you were using v6.  The new equivalent is `ol.sphere.getDistance` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html

Comment: I can confirm ol.sphere.getDistance works thanks Mike. I just needed to covert my coordinates back to lng/lat pairs first.